# Error-CS0006 metadata file could not be found

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, .net-framework-version

I'm facing some errors while I set up the backend in my system. I had seven errors of this kind ("metadata file could not be found"), along with one error saying you missed a using directive or an assembly reference, 
look like

1. Error    CS0006    Metadata file 'abc.DAL.EF.dll' could not be found
2. Error    CS0006    Metadata file 'abc.DAL.EF.dll' could not be found
3. Error    CS0006    Metadata file 'abc.Logging.dll' could not be found
4. Error    CS0006    Metadata file 'abc.BAL.Providers.dll' could not be
   found
5. Error    CS0006    Metadata file 'abc.DAL.EF.dll' could not be found
6. Error    CS0006    Metadata file 'abc.Logging.dll' could not be found
7. Error    CS1061    'AbcDbContext' does not contain a definition for 'SubIssues' and no accessible extension method 'SubIssues' accepting a first argument of type 'AbcDbContext' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   abc.DAL.EF

Based on my research, I follow the following steps:

1. I was going to **'Solution Explorer**', open 'Properties' and open **"**Configuration Manager." **"Build**" is unchecked, then check them and try building again.

2. Add the extension target framework Migrator.

3. Clean the solution and try again to rebuild the project.

4. Unload the project and load it again. I also attached the screenshot below for reference. Can anyone help me to figure out what I'm missing here?

etc.
Can anyone help me to figure out what I'm missing here?